Oracle - Shell - Have a list of users to create in DB
In Oracle database, I have to create a list of users from a external SQL file - create_users.sql.
I am trying to automate a refresh process of data from one db to another db. I was successful in doing the data part after user creation. During user creation I am facing the below problem.
I am using whenever sqlerror exit 1, and if the users exist in the database, its exiting. I need a way to handle that exception that if a user exists, it should continue, whereas for other errors let's say if a table space doesn't exist for the user, it should exit.
I am looking for way to handle this with a way to continue only when user exists error comes and upon other errors this should exit.
I am not sure of how to pull this sql into a PL/SQL code if that is the only way to do.
sqlplus -s "/nolog" <<EOF >$WORK_DIR/sqls/${pdbtns}_${DATE}_create_users.log
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;
connect / as sysdba
set head off feed off pages 0
set serveroutput on
@create_users.sql
EOF

Here is sample of create_users.sql, it contains user creation scripts for 500+ users with table grants, system grants and roles grants.
create_users.sql
create user vijay identified by vijay;
create user ramesh identified by ramesh;
grant select_catalog_role to vijay;
grant select on app1.table_name1 to vijay;
grant select_catalog_role to ramesh;
grant select on app1.table_name1 to ramesh;


sqlcl only has the "WHENEVER SQLERROR". There is no way to indicate specific behavior for individual errors. Trapping specific errors can be done in pl/sql. In pl/sql DDL statements can  executed using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.
First determine the error you need to trap:

The oracle error code is 01920. Use pragma EXCEPTION_INIT to associate your user defined exception to an oracle error code. Then trap the error in the exception block.
DECLARE
  e_user_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(e_user_exists, -01920);
  l_statement VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_statement := 'create user KOEN no authentication temporary tablespace temp default tablespace data';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement;
EXCEPTION WHEN   e_user_exists THEN
  NULL;
END;
/

Run this block and notice the error is ignored as expected:

Another error will still cause the script to fail:

One possibility is to create a (temporary) table and load the statements in the table then loop through that table with pl/sql and execute all statements using the technique above.
